# how to change overall index when one of the row is removed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table structure(users):

- ID(index , auto increment)
- Name

Here's the current rows inside this table(users):

```
ID   NAME
---------
1    John
2    Mike
3    Harry
4    Christine
```

When i remove row 2 using php , which is Mike's row . how can i change harry 's ID into 2 and christine id into 3 using php?

so it WONT look like:

```
ID   NAME 
-----------
1    John
3    Harry
4    Christine
```

...so it will look like:

```
ID   NAME
---------
1    John
2    Harry
3    Christine
```

Comment: You probably don't want to do that; it's a generally bad idea. What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you think you need to change ids?

Comment: Are you *trying* to destroy your database?

Comment: Don't, especially if ID is your primary key.

Comment: do you want to change the id in database or in html page

Comment: I agree with Ryan. In most cases, this can have really bad effects. If you have another table that holds arbitrary entities and the user id of the user that owns them, then changing the user ids will cause harry to lose ownership of his entities and gain ownership of Mike's

Comment: an ID is an unique identifier for the item in that row. let's say we visit Harry's profile like `mysite.com/profile.php?id=3` and shared to everyone in the link. if you do what you want to do, that is to shift the ID to the next user, if Harry deleted his account, everyone would see Christine in those shared links (and then everyone would say *"who in the world is this person?"*). and for a database that holds users that can come and go in the site... you know what happens

Comment: im making a slider that requires a number to know which slide that data is located,

Comment: Auto_increment field is there for a purpose, if you want to display in front end use count not id

Comment: if ids are deleted at the end, you can reclaim those ids using `Alter table tableName auto_increment=4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good to reset `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. specially when you have relational database.

However if if you want, then Before delete you need to get max value of `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and  after deleting you need to reset AUTO_INCREMENT field according to max value

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = value
```

This will reset the next auto_increment to be used to the given value.